# How to print out -e with echo

Tags: shell, unix, echo

I am new to unix and just started with the shell and its commands. I have to do a few tasks for an assignment.
And my Question is how do I print out -e with echo. I know there is the $ printf '%s\n' -e Option, but i have to use echo.

Comment: is this some homework assignment, or why do you have to use echo? As programmer, you try to use the right tool, if possible, and in this case, that'd probably be `printf`.

Comment: What should `-e` do since the only option defined is`-n`? Additionally, `echo` has some limitations. Please see [docs] ru(http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?echo) for further information.

Comment: @albert He's using bash's echo, which uses `-e` to mean "allow backslash escapes." The man page is for /bin/echo, which is different. Check the bash man page for all details.

Comment: @Marcus Müller: Yes, its a homework assignment, and thats why i have to use echo.

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
echo -e "\055e"
```

If you are ever unsure of the ASCII codes (like `\055` above), you can easily check them out with

```
man ascii
```

> NAME
>        ascii -- octal, hexadecimal and decimal ASCII character sets
>
> DESCRIPTION
>        The octal set:
>
> ```
>  000 nul  001 soh  002 stx  003 etx  004 eot  005 enq  006 ack  007 bel
>  010 bs   011 ht   012 nl   013 vt   014 np   015 cr   016 so   017 si
>  020 dle  021 dc1  022 dc2  023 dc3  024 dc4  025 nak  026 syn  027 etb
>  030 can  031 em   032 sub  033 esc  034 fs   035 gs   036 rs   037 us
>  040 sp   041  !   042  "   043  #   044  $   045  %   046  &   047  '
>  050  (   051  )   052  *   053  +   054  ,   055  -   056  .   057  /
>  060  0   061  1   062  2   063  3   064  4   065  5   066  6   067  7
>  070  8   071  9   072  :   073  ;   074  <   075  =   076  >   077  ?
>  100  @   101  A   102  B   103  C   104  D   105  E   106  F   107  G
>  110  H   111  I   112  J   113  K   114  L   115  M   116  N   117  O
>  120  P   121  Q   122  R   123  S   124  T   125  U   126  V   127  W
>  130  X   131  Y   132  Z   133  [   134  \   135  ]   136  ^   137  _
>  140  `   141  a   142  b   143  c   144  d   145  e   146  f   147  g
>  150  h   151  i   152  j   153  k   154  l   155  m   156  n   157  o
>  160  p   161  q   162  r   163  s   164  t   165  u   166  v   167  w
>  170  x   171  y   172  z   173  {   174  |   175  }   176  ~   177 del
> ```

Comment: When I responded Marcus that I didn't know the ASCII codes, I only meant that I did not know it by heart. When the alarm rings early, then I stutter `s/sound/silence/g` and not `cut -d "\007" -f7-`. Upvote.

Answer (score -1):

You need some work-around.
How about:

```
echo "x-u" | cut -c2-
```

or

```
echo "I want to learn sed x-e" | sed 's/.*x//'
```

Comment: I do think this is not really any better than using `printf`; basically you could just pipe anything into `printf`, e.g. `echo "" | printf '%s' -e`; so if he's not allowed to use `printf` he's pretty surely not allowed to use `sed`, `cut` etc.

Comment: @Marcus: I just don't know. The answer of Mark seems best, but I didn't know the ASCII codes. For homework, learning how you can deal with problems like an unrealistic restriction of the forbidden use of printf, might be interesting for the OP.

Comment: good point, really. I'd take from this: sometimes, school (and usually a bit less often, work) gives you arbitrary restrictions. Finding your way through this is the real challenge, and hence, your answer is pretty valuable.

Comment: @Marcus Was the downvote yours?